# Swagger: Using JAX-RS Map for body params

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger

I am trying to setup Swagger in our existing JAX-RS REST project to document our API.

In the case of operations where we take in a JSON request body we have been using this idiom:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value="Some operation")
@ApiImplicitParams(value={
        @ApiImplicitParam(name="val1", value="Input 1", dataType="string", paramType="body"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name="val2", value="Input 2", dataType="string", paramType="body")
})
public Response login(Map<String, Object> request) { }
```

By taking in a Map JAX-RS maps the JSON object into the map to access values by key name. This is nice and avoid requiring a model for every single such operation.

However, Swagger scans such operations and automatically includes the Map as a request parameter. My intention is that I am defining the parameters properly in the @ApiImplicitParams annotation. Is there a way to get Swagger to ignore the Map and just use the parameters defined in @ApiImplicitParams?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and used

```
public Response login(@Context Map<String, Object> request) { }
```

This essentially hid the actual param from the output. The annotation comes from

```
javax.ws.rs.core
```